# How to rerender a component when it contains a helper?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, helper, rerender

## The problem

I'm trying to rerender a component after an action, but the part of the template i need to rerender is not updated, because it comes from the result of a helper i made, or at least i think it's because of that.

In my component template, i have something like this :

```
{{my-helper value}}
```

In the component js file associated, i have this action :

```
fillGrid(location, length) {
  /* logic */

  this.rerender();
},
```

## How i did

I found a way to do it but it felt weird, i'm using a booelan that i toggle between true and false in the action to force rerender

```
fillGrid(location, length) {
    let me = this;
    this.set('show', false);

    /* logic */

    Ember.run.later(function() {
      me.set('show', true);
      me.rerender();
    }, 10);
}
```

And in the template :

```
{{#if show}}
    {{my-helper value}}
{{/if}}
```

Is it the right way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `this.rerender()` explicitly. If you changed `value` property then `my-helper` will be called automatically to recompute and it will be displayed in component template.